# Change Margins on HTML export to Word

Tags: html, ms-word, export, margin

The actual export is no problem:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/word");
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}.doc", docName));
Response.Charset = "utf-8";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
mainbody.RenderControl(hw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

So my question is: How do I change the margins on the resulting word doc?

If I open the downloaded word doc then save as HTML, the directive that defines the margins is:

```
@page WordSection1
{
  size:8.5in 11.0in;
  margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;
  mso-header-margin:.5in;
  mso-footer-margin:.5in;
  mso-paper-source:0;
}
```

I'm wondering how I can change this in the response headers so I can output the form correctly on one sheet.  Any ideas?

Comment: Any luck with this?  We are generating a html document that contains Images and the right margin is set so images and text are being hidden.  Its actually the table column.

Comment: It is easier to learn how to write HTML yourself than to try to make software do it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I solved this, in VB.NET rather than C#. I got the [code from here](http://techsynapse.blogspot.com/2007/03/generating-word-document-dynamically.html):

```
divContent.RenderControl(New HtmlTextWriter(New IO.StringWriter(sb)))

memoBody = sb.ToString

Response.Clear()
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & fileName & "")
Response.ContentType = "application/msword"
Dim sbResponseString As New StringBuilder
Dim wordHeader as String = "<html xmlns:o=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"" "
wordHeader &= "xmlns:w=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"" "
wordHeader &= "xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40""> "
wordHeader &= "<head><title>Document Title</title>"
wordHeader &= "<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><w:WordDocument><w:View>Print</w:View><w:Zoom>100</w:Zoom>"
wordHeader &= "<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/></w:WordDocument></xml><![endif]-->"
wordHeader &= "<style> @page Section1 {size:8.5in 11.0in; mso-first-footer:ff1; mso-footer: f1; mso-header: h1; "
wordHeader &= "border:solid navy 2.25pt; padding:24.0pt 24.0pt 24.0pt 24.0pt; "
wordHeader &= "margin:0.75in 0.50in 0.75in 0.50in ; mso-header-margin:.5in; "
wordHeader &= "mso-footer-margin:.5in; mso-paper-source:0;} "
wordHeader &= "div.Section1 {page:Section1;} p.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, "
wordHeader &= "div.MsoFooter{margin:0in; margin-bottom:.0001pt; "
wordHeader &= "mso-pagination:widow-orphan; tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in; "
wordHeader &= "font-size:12.0pt; font-family:'Arial';} "
wordHeader &= "p.MsoHeader, li.MsoHeader, div.MsoHeader {margin:0in; "
wordHeader &= "margin-bottom:.0001pt; mso-pagination:widow-orphan; tab-stops:center "
wordHeader &= "3.0in right 6.0in; font-size:12.0pt; font-family:'Arial';}--></style></head> "

Dim wordBody as String = "<body><div class=Section1>" & memoBody & "</div></body></html>"

sbResponseString.Append(wordHeader)
sbResponseString.Append(wordBody)

Dim newResponseString As String = sbResponseString.ToString
Response.Write(newResponseString)
Response.End()
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier, if your circumstances permit, emit a docx file which is basically a few zipped XML files, as this will allow you to control page layout aspects (and lots of other stuff obviously).

Then you can take the rest of your HTML and embed it into a section of the docx file using the altChunk element.

Ref: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32907/HTML-to-WordML

It's more work that what you might have liked, but you will gain all manner of control over your output document.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the simplest solution in my case, using Word 2013, was to link CSS to the saved HTML. This gives me control over margins and anything else I may want to tweak.

Find the option under Developer tab -> Document Template -> Linked CSS.

Credit: https://superuser.com/questions/65107/how-to-apply-external-css-stylesheet-to-document-in-microsoft-word/65144#65144